# Using DESCRIPTIVE PROGRAMMING, how QTP11, can find the Link (Web Link) in the web page

Tags: qtp

I am new to QTP and am trying to use version 11 to automate my project.

Using descriptive programming, how QTP can find a link in a web page. The HTML for the link is written in the Onclick function (like `onclick="navigationClick('Link Name');`)

I tried this:

```
If Browser(Browsername).Page(Pagename).Link("html tag:='Value',"id:=X","title:=Y","class:=Z").Exist(50)Then
   Browser(Browsername).Page(Pagename).Link("html tag:='Value',"id:=X","title:=Y","class:=Z").click

Else

 MsgBox "Link cannot be found"
```

But when i run the script, it always shows Link Cannot be found.

Note:

Using the same descriptive programming, i can able to find the link in the web page, if the HTML for the link is wrriten as `OnClick='javascript.navigationClick(Link);"href='javascript:void(0);`

Answer (score 4):

On second reading of your question I think the problem is that the link you're trying to identify doesn't have an `href`. QTP does not consider links with no `href` to be real links. Perhaps if you try to use a `WebElement` rather than a `Link` the identification will succeed.

Also note that QTP uses the `html id` property instead of the DOM's `id`.

```
Browser(B).Page(P).WebElement("html tag:=A", "html id:=X").Click
```

(my original answer follows)

---

You can access the `onclick` attribute by using the `attribute/` syntax for accessing native DOM attributes.

```
Browser(B).Page(P).Link("attribute/onclick:=navigationClick\('Link Name'\);")
```

Note that descriptive programming uses regular expressions so you have to escape special characters (like the parentheses in this example).

Comment: Hi Motti, I had tried using attribute which mentioned.But seems it's not working (I am not sure whether i tried it in the wrong way)... Here is the actual HTML for the link <a title="Purchase History" class="TertiaryNav" id="Purchases" style="cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none;" onclick="navigationClick('MYPURCHASES');">

I had tried like this

Comment: If Browser("Browsername").Page("Pagename").Link("html tag:=A","id:=Purchases","title:=Purchase History","class:=TertiaryNav","attribute/onclick:=navigationClick\('MYPURCHASES'\);").Exist(50) Then




    Browser("Browsername").Page("PageName").Link("html tag:=A","id:=Purchases","title:=Purchase History","class:=TertiaryNav","attribute/onclick:=navigationClick\('MYPURCHASES'\);").Click  

but there is no luck

Comment: @Karthickeyan as I said QTP doesn't consider links with no `href` to be real links, try using `WebElement` instead of `Link`